# Adding multiple sheets on active workbook after excisting sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I have been doing a code that makes a new workbooks and adds sheets(amount of days) in selected mm/yyyy in inputbox and then adds first sheet for totals.
Unfortunately this didn't turn out to be the best solution for what I'm trying to do.

Now I would like the code to do everythin that it does atm but instead of creating new workbook, it would add the "total for" and day sheets on the currently active workbook where I have command button for this code. I'm also trying to do so, that all the new sheets would be added after the existing sheets(2).

Here is my current code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub CreateNewBookWithDaysInMonthSheets()

Dim WS As Worksheet, WB As Workbook
Dim MonthX As Date, Control As Variant, DaysInMonth As Byte, I As Byte, _
LMonth As Integer, LValue As String, LYear As Integer

'create input box
Control = InputBox("Create new FTE workbook for period:", "New FTE", "mm/yyyy")
If IsDate(Control) Then
    'Create sheets based on days in selected month
    MonthX = CDate(Control)
    DaysInMonth = Day(DateSerial(Year(MonthX), Month(MonthX) + 1, 0))
    Application.SheetsInNewWorkbook = DaysInMonth
    Set WB = Workbooks.Add

    I = 1
    For Each WS In WB.Sheets
        WS.Name = I
        I = I + 1

        'set default workbook count back to 3
        Application.SheetsInNewWorkbook = 3
    Next

LMonth = Month(Control)
LValue = MonthName(LMonth)
LYear = Year(Control)

'add first sheet for totals, name total for date value in InputBox
Set WS = Sheets.Add(Before:=Sheets("1"))
WS.Name = "Total for " & LValue & "_" & LYear

    'Tables content
        For Each WS In WB.Worksheets
        Columns("A:A").Select
        Selection.ColumnWidth = 27

        Columns("C:P").Select
        Selection.ColumnWidth = 5.3

        Rows("2:2").Select
        Selection.RowHeight = 113

        Range("A1").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = LValue & " " & LYear

    Next
Else
    MsgBox "No period set"
End If
End Sub
```

If it's ok to ask for the following also here, I would appreciate some advice:
How can I refer to the created day sheets so that the code could automatically filter out weekends? I'm going to make a userform, based on which, there will be data filled to weekdays only. Is this even possible?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code below, which will only add new worksheets for non-Saturdays and non-Sundays in a given month:

```
Option Explicit
Sub DoCoolStuff()

Dim WS As Worksheet, WB As Workbook
Dim MonthX As Date
Dim Control As Variant
Dim DaysInMonth As Long, LMonth As Long, LYear As Long, _
    Index As Long, DayNumOfWeek As Long
Dim LValue As String

'create input box
Control = InputBox("Create new FTE workbook for period:", "New FTE", "mm/yyyy")
If IsDate(Control) Then
    'Create sheets based on days in selected month
    MonthX = CDate(Control)
    DaysInMonth = Day(DateSerial(Year(MonthX), Month(MonthX) + 1, 0))
    Set WB = ThisWorkbook

    'loop through month, creating days
    For Index = 1 To DaysInMonth
        'only want day numbers 1-5, day 6 is Saturday and day 7 is Sunday
        DayNumOfWeek = Weekday(DateAdd("d", Index - 1, MonthX), 2)
        If DayNumOfWeek <> 6 And DayNumOfWeek <> 7 Then
            Set WS = WB.Worksheets.Add(After:=ActiveSheet)
            WS.Name = Index
        End If
    Next Index

    LMonth = Month(Control)
    LValue = MonthName(LMonth)
    LYear = Year(Control)

    'add first sheet for totals, name total for date value in InputBox
    Set WS = Sheets.Add(Before:=ActiveSheet)
    WS.Name = "Total for " & LValue & "_" & LYear

    'format sheets
    For Each WS In WB.Worksheets
        With WS
            .Columns("A:A").ColumnWidth = 27
            .Columns("C:P").ColumnWidth = 5.3
            .Rows("2:2").RowHeight = 113
            .Range("A1").FormulaR1C1 = LValue & " " & LYear
        End With
    Next WS
Else
    MsgBox "No period set"
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Dan, this was really helpful and gave me a push to the direction I wanted to go. As the added sheets are excluded of weekends in the beginning, this makes things much easier going forward. Thank you again!

Comment: Great -- if an answer suits you, please accept it at your convenience. Here's a super-quick explanation in the form of a screenshot: http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png